# How can I get the hostname from a file using awk and regex or substring

Tags: regex, bash, awk

The file name is in a format like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DD_hostname_something.log
```

I want to get the hostname from the filename. The hostname can be any length, but always has a _ before and after. This is my current awk statement. It worked fine until the hostname length changed. Now I can't use it anymore.

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } FNR == 1 { d = substr(FILENAME, 1, 10) } { h = substr(FILENAME, 12, 10) } $2 ~ /^[AP]M$/ && $3 != "CPU" { print d, $1 "" $2, h, $4+$5, $6, $7+$8+$9}' *_something.log > myfile.log
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 'YYYY-MM-DD_hostname_something.log' | awk -F"_" '{print $2}'
```

Output:

```
hostname
```

I suppose your hostname contains no `_`.

Comment: Try this: `find -name "*_something.log" | awk -F"_" '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ls YYYY-MM-DD_hostname_something.log | cut -d _ -f 2
hostname
```

The `cut(1)` utility is POSIX and accepts the `-d _` option to specify a delimiter and `-f 2` to specify the second field. It has got a few more nifty options that you can read about in its [fine manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned you need to modify your awk code, replace your substr function with split.

```
split(FILENAME,a,"_");date = a[1];host = a[2]
```

- split the FILENAME value into array a with _ as FS.
- a[1] will contain date
- a[2] will contain the hostname value.